# How to transfer properties between different projects in SoapUI

Tags: soapui

I am new to SoapUi and need some help with following scenario:

I have two project, each has different WSDL file associated with it

Project1: 
**Administration**
->Login
->Logout

Project2:
**Retrieval**
->Search

How do I transfer properties (UserID, AuthToken) from soap response in Login testcase from project 1 to Soap request in  'Search' testcase in Project2?

I have tried by adding test step 'Property Transfer' but that only return list of testcases under Project1 (e.g. 'Logout') but not the testcase under Project2 (Search)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using groovy script test step:

```
//get test case from other project
project = testRunner.getTestCase().getTestSuite().getProject().getWorkspace().getProjectByName(project_name)
testSuite = project.getTestSuiteByName(suite_name);
testCase = testSuite.getTestCaseByName(testcase_name);

//set properties
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue(property_name, property_value);
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue(another_property_name, another_property_value);

// run test case
runner = testCase.run(new com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap(), false);
```

Comment: btw, why you don't just put all requests and test cases in one project?

Comment: Thank you Artem but I've managed to find a workaround which was to call multiple web services within a single project which then enabled me to have access to the login testcase.

Comment: Do you try to use groovy script for this, as I wrote above? The other way is to write your properties to txt file or properties file in Project1 with groovy script and then load properties from this file in Project2, so you don't have to run testcases from Project2 in Project1.

Comment: Given that I've now restructured my tests, no I haven't tried the groovy solution. However in case if I come across the same issue again will refer to your solution :)

Thanks a bunch for your help though :)

Comment: @user929258 I know its an old thread, but how did you manage to get multiple soap web services in single project? Thanks.