# How can we transfer property values through two Separate projects in SOAP UI?

Tags: soap, soapui, soap-client, ksoap2

I have two separate SOAP UI projects for two SOAP calls. A property value from the SOAP response of first project is a dependency of the SOAP request of second project. So I'm try to pass that value from first project to second. But all the time it doesn't show transfer value and said error about missing properties. Does anyone know a way to avoid this error and pass property value among two projects in SoapUI?

I'm using SoapUI 5.2 in windows environment.

Comment: Your question is very unspecific. Please give us some code and wthat you have tried so far...

Comment: Not sure what is your use case. In general, it is best practice that each test case should be independent. You are looking to have dependency between the projects which is not right way to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Groovy Script for transfer properties in between projects as follows.

```
// set properties 
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("property_name","property_value");

// set properties 
def property_name = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("property_name");
```

For further reference, Please read following answer. 
[How to transfer properties between different projects in SoapUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648474/how-to-transfer-properties-between-different-projects-in-soapui)