# How to transfer property between projects

Tags: testing, soap, groovy, soapui

How can I transfer property between two different projects in SoapUI?
can I do it using property test step and property transfer test step or do I have to use groovy? Thank you

Comment: Instead of answering, let me just refer to already existing answers. 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648474/how-to-transfer-properties-between-different-projects-in-soapui, 2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36570269/how-to-pass-parameter-from-one-project-to-another-project

Comment: It is recommended to have each test case independent. Here you are trying to bring in the dependency between the projects which is not recommended at all.